# Calculating μ(A\ B) in probability space

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics, linear-algebra, sigma-algebra

I am new in learning sigma-algebra. My question is related to computing μ(A\ B). I just need the hints and ideas on how to do it, I will do it.

Let (X,Ao,μ) be a probability space. It is given that A, B and C are 3 sets such that μ(A∩B) = 3/5 , μ(A∩C) = 3/5 and μ(B∩C) = 3/5. μ(A∩B∩C) = 2/5.

How can I calculate μ(A\ B) from these? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram

Comment: Draw a Venn-diagram. If I made no mistakes myself then it is not possible to find $\mu(A\setminus B)$ on base of these data. You can at most find borders for the probability.

Comment: Is there any formula for computing μ(A\ B) in general cases?

Comment: @hadyaali At most something like $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(A)-\mu(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544270/show-mua-cap-b-cap-c-leq-min-mua-cap-b-mua-cap-c-mub-cap-c

Comment: @drhab If you see your Venn diagram as a partition of $\mu(X)=1$ into $8$ parts, you know $μ(A∩B∩C) = \frac25$ and can work out $μ(A∩B^c∩C) $ $= μ(A∩C) - μ(A∩B∩C)$ $=\frac35-\frac25$ $=\frac15$ etc., leaving four parts whose measure is easily found and so $\mu(A \backslash B)=μ(A∩B^c∩C)+μ(A∩B^c∩C^c)$

Comment: @Henry That is indeed a better expression for $\mu(A\setminus B)$ in this context of Venn-diagrams.

Comment: @drhab: my point - more aimed at the OP than you - was following your suggestion of a Venn diagram in this particular example actually provides a numerical answer.

Comment: @Henry Oh, I see now. I overlooked that $\frac15+\frac15+\frac15+\frac25=1$ leaving no room anymore. Fortunately a part of my comment was: "...if I made no mistakes.."

Comment: Please see the [hits at this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=venn+diagram+prob*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5) for many worked examples of this kind of exercise.